# Which package do I need for Images in asp.net 5?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Previously it was System.Drawing namespace for images. I am not sure which library do I need in asp.net 5 to have an object of `Image` type.

Comment: Asking for a library is not considered a good question on SO, however I think this a problem many people will hit (I have) when upgrading projects to ASP.NET 5, so you have my +1

Answer (score 8):

There's a bunch of libraries that can fill the gap, afaik there is no drop in replacement for System.Drawing.

I've hit the same problem and I'm looking at these libs:

- http://imageresizing.net
- http://imageprocessor.org/

**Update**

Looks these libs are not quite ready to work without System.Drawing yet.
There are reports that you can still reference System.Drawing if an older .Net version is installed on the server. Add the following bits to your project.json:

```
"frameworks": {
    "aspnet50": {
         "dependencies": {
             "System.Drawing": ""
        }
    }
}
```

More info on this topic here: https://github.com/imazen/Graphics-vNext .
The gist of that discussion is that there is no real alternative yet.

**Update 2**

Scott Hanselman has [blogged](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/RFCServersideImageAndGraphicsProcessingWithNETCoreAndASPNET5.aspx) about this. Seems that server side image processing is not a priority at all for Microsoft at this point.

So for now the best bet is still on the projects mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks! I am going to try one of these.

Comment: ImageProcessor Core is being written just now for .NET Core https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageProcessor/tree/Core/

Answer (score 0):

I add this package from nuget and fixed the issue

```
System.Drawing.Common
```